# Hybrid Apps and Storage - how does it work with Native apps and which to use?

Tags: database, android, ios, local-storage, indexeddb

I'm using Ionic at the moment. I believe, like many others, that hybrid apps will become more more common/important than they are now simply because the frameworks are getting better and better.

Anyway, I'm building two cross-platform (iOS/Android) apps that need to store data about the user. Partly these are user settings, and I'm going to use localStorage for this, but both apps are specifically for recording data and I don't know where to store this.

I'm unsure what sort of data store to use. All this data is text or numbers so the 5Mb limit of localStorage or webSQL or IndexedDB shouldn't be an issues. Supposedly that's enough for The Complete Works of Shakespeare and the records I want to record aren't large.

I suppose there is a larger issue here. I don't know how native apps do it as I've never developed for native. How does the Gmail app store it's data? How does the Facebook or WhatsApp app do it? Is it in a SQLite DB or the File System? Or something else?

I guess it's my lack of understanding how these apps work that is contributing to my confusion. If the 5Mb limit on those storage spaces wasn't there I'd use localForage.

Can anyone offer any insight?

Comment: Non-trivial applications such as Gmail, Facebook and Whatsapp store their data on a server somewhere on the Internet, and access it via web services.  For the most part, they don't use SQLite; they use something more industrial-strength, like SQL Server, Postgresql or possibly a NoSQL database.  5MB is not that much; you can blow that whole load with one high-resolution photograph.

Comment: I know how small 5Mb is for images, but for text is loads, no?

Comment: Until it isn't.

Comment: Complete Works of Shakespeare not enough?

Comment: I promise you, when (not if) that 5MB runs out, you're not going to be a happy camper.